# getUserMedia hangs in incognito

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})` hangs in my tab, no errors or anything. Expected: prompt for permissions

Has anyone encountered this issue before? It only happens to me in Chrome incognito mode. Firefox private browser works as expected

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you've already denied permission for the origin server you're using. Incognito has its own lists of allows and denials, separate from the usual Chromium mode you use.

To diagnose this kind of thing look at the console in your browser devtools. It may say "DOMException: permission denied."

Also, you can click on the lock icon just to the left of the URL while the page is displaying. It will show you the current permission situation, and give you a way to change it.

Comment: It turns out there was some async WebRTC negotiation logic occurring that led to this. A workaround was to use dummy video/audio tracks, and the permissions prompt appears fine